# How do you move a Gerrit Change to a different branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, gerrit

In our Gerrit setup we do not have the `Move Change` plugin enabled, yet we have a lot of changes on branch A, which we want to move to branch B with minimal distribution.

The only way I've found to do this thus far is to checkout the change on branch A on a local repo, then:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/B
```

This creates a new change, on branch B, "Cherry Picked" from the change I'm trying move on branch A. This means we'd need to abandon the old change on branch A, thus creating more of a mess than I'd like (we'd essentially be duplicating every change we want to move).

Is there any way to just move the change via the git CLI? I'd prefer to update the branch in a similar manner as one would upload a new changeset and not create a new change.

Comment: If you want to move all commits on A to B, use `git checkout B && git merge A --no-ff && git push origin HEAD:refs/for/B`. If you want some of the commits, use `git cherry-pick` instead. In the latter case, it's not proper to checkout a commit on A and then push to `refs/for/B`, because it will mingle A and B like merging A to B.

Comment: @ElpieKay : I'm afraid this doesn't really answer the question. What you describe creates a merge commit on branch B within Gerrit. The change in on branch A still exists within Gerrit and will need submitted on branch A before the merge commit can be submitted. The solution I'd like (though I'm starting to think may not exist), is to move a change in Gerrit to another branch, with no other changes necessary.

Comment: It's impossible to do it without new changes unless one of the unsubmitted changes of A happens to be the perfect new tip of B, in which case you can reset B to this commit and force-push B, or force-push this commit to update B, without making any new change.

Comment: Thank you for your help @ElpieKay . I assumed it was impossible but thank you confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Move Change` is not a plugin but a core feature, available since version 2.13.  Since version 3.0.0 it's possible to [disable it on the server config](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/3.0.3/config-gerrit.html#change.move). (Note that the config is available since 3.0.0 but only documented since 3.0.3).

If the version of Gerrit is older than 2.13, or 3.0.0 or later with the feature disabled, it's not possible to move a change's destination branch. You would have to abandon it and re-upload a new one to the correct branch.

For 3.0.0+ you could ask the server admin to enable the feature, although if it's disabled it means it was disabled deliberately; it's enabled by default. One reason people might want to disable it is that it doesn't automatically rebase moved changes on the new destination, which can cause unwanted commits to be included.  See [issue 12216](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=12216).

Comment: Thank you very much for this response David. I believe we have this plugin disabled so I've decided the best approach is to persuade the server admin to enable this.